# Copying Table Values to a New Sheet in a Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

So I've already had this piece of code tweaked on here for another reason. [Searching through List Object Table's Column in For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072477/searching-through-list-object-tables-column-in-for-loop)

Essentially the issue at hand boils down to the fact that I want to loop through a table, and if a row meets certain criteria I want to copy the value over to a new tab (for later use.)

I've done this before by using a variable called RowToPastteTo to get to the next empty row and have followed the same structure as before, but or some reason all of the code runs without a debugging issue, but just doesn't copy the values over.

Here is the full code

```
Sub RequestedAssetList()

Dim FullAssLi As ListObject, RowRange As ListRow  'Defining the Table and Range
Set FullAssLi = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Asset List").ListObjects("AssListTab") 'Set FullAsset Lists as the Asset Table



    With ThisWorkbook 'Within the workbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Assets" 'Adds a sheet at the end of the workbook called Assets
    End With


     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assets")
        Dim RowToPasteTo As Long
        'RowToPasteTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        RowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Sets variable as the next exmpy row on column A of Assets' tab


            For Each RowRange In FullAssLi.ListRows
            If RowRange.Range.Cells(9).Value = UserForm2.SourceLiBo.Value Then 'If Data Source matches userform criteria then
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assets").Range("A1").Value = RowRange.Range.Cells(2).Value


'
''
                End If
            Next

     End With
End Sub
```

It seems that the problem line is **`If RowRange.Range.Cells(9).Value = UserForm2.SourceLiBo.Value Then
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assets").Range("A1").Value = RowRange.Range.Cells(2).Value`**

How can I get this to copy the figures from the `FullAssL` into the new Assets sheet?

I've played around, changing that line of code to changing the back ground colour of RowRange.Cells(9) and still nothing.

Comment: Maybe the compared values contain trailing spaces? You could try to apply the Trim function (cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions).

Comment: THANK YOU!! It reminded me that the userform uses the full name but the data in Column 9 only had the first name! Amended now and all is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no errors, indeed. By the way, if i'm well thinking, you are pasting the value at the same cell ever. If you want a list of values, you have to increment your row reference like:

```
  Dim i
  i = 1
  For Each RowRange In FullAssLi.ListRows
      If RowRange.Range.Cells(9).Value = UserForm2.SourceLiBo.Value Then
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assets").Range("A" & i).Value = RowRange.Range.Cells(2).Value
          i = i + 1 
      End If
  Next
```

Comment: Hi there! Oooh I didn't notice that, was andering why it all went to one cell. I've changed that now, thank you!